# How is the compare() method called, without calling it in main method?

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.*;

class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{
    public int compare(String aStr, String bStr) {
        return bStr.compareTo(aStr);
    }
}


public class CustomComparatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyComp my = new MyComp();
        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(my);
        ts.add("C");
        ts.add("A");
        ts.add("B");
        ts.add("Y");
        ts.add("T");
        ts.add("W");

        for(String element : ts)
        {
            System.out.println(element + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you be more specific? It seems you are trying to use String comparator to keep elements order, but TreeSet acctualy keeps it though :)

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on the method and run this in your debugger you will see how and why it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean add(E e) {return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;}
```

when you call **add(x)** function, in TreeSet it call **TreeMap.put()** method, in **TreeMap.put()**, it will call **comparator**. source code like that:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
        Entry<K,V> t = root;
        if (t == null) {
            compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

            root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
            size = 1;
            modCount++;
            return null;
        }
        int cmp;
        Entry<K,V> parent;
        // split comparator and comparable paths
        Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        else {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(key, value, parent);
        if (cmp < 0)
            parent.left = e;
        else
            parent.right = e;
        fixAfterInsertion(e);
        size++;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are asking how the compare method is executed without being called explicitly in your main method, it is called by the `TreeSet` code each time you add an element to it, in order to locate the position in the `TreeSet` where the element should be stored. This way `TreeSet` maintains the elements sorted according to the order dictated by the `Comparator` you passed to its constructor.

Comment: I'm asking that How the compare() method is calling even we are not calling it in main method?

Comment: @VinayGuru That's what I answered. You are calling `add`, which causes `compare` to be called.

Comment: Note that a single `add()` call may cause `compare` to be call multiple times.